# MongooseJS findOne returning full document, even with .select()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm at a total loss with this. I have multiple different calls going to different endpoints dealing with specific subdocuments. I have not had an issue up til this point. Most of the time, I run the query as such:

```
exports.getClientContracts = async (req, res) => {
   try{
        const client = await Client.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
        const contracts = client.contracts;
        res.send(contracts)  
    } catch {
        res.status(404)
        res.send({error: "Contracts not found"})
    }
})
```

and it works just fine. For example, running that query brings just the array of contract subdocs from the Client model that matches the id criteria:

```
[
    {
        "authNumber": "1",
        "contType": "Quarterly",
        "contHours": 60,
        "contStartDate": "2022-01-01T08:00:00.000Z",
        "contEndDate": "2022-04-01T07:00:00.000Z",
        "_id": "6283e6bf87fb0fdbd26045fa",
        "createdAt": "2022-05-17T18:17:35.127Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-17T18:17:35.127Z",
        "contractId": 50
    },
    {
        "authNumber": "2",
        "contType": "Monthly",
        "contHours": 20,
        "contStartDate": "2022-01-01T08:00:00.000Z",
        "contEndDate": "2022-06-01T07:00:00.000Z",
        "_id": "6286e91853e338fd260ed421",
        "createdAt": "2022-05-20T01:04:24.820Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-05-20T01:04:24.820Z",
        "contractId": 63
    }
]
```

However, when interacting only with this particular model ("ServicePlan"), no matter how I'm writing the queries it is returning the full parent document and subdocs, rather than just the specified fields. I have 2 queries for different subdocs- the first written the way that has been working for me:

```
exports.getClientReportNotes = async (req, res) => {
   
    try{
     const servicePlan = await ServicePlan.findOne({ _id: req.params.planId})
     const notes = servicePlan.notes;
     res.send(notes)
    } catch {
        res.status(404)
        res.send({ error: "No notes found for this client report"})
    }
 }
```

and the second using .select() since that method has not been working, which should be straightforward:
(https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/find-certain-fields)

```
exports.getClientReportGoals = async (req, res) => {
    
    await ServicePlan.findOne({ _id: req.params.planId})
        .select('goals')
        .exec(function(err, goals) {
            if (goals) {
                res.send(goals)
            } else if (err) {
                res.status(404)
                res.send({ error: "No goals found for this client report"})
            }
        })
 }
```

either way returns the entire parent ServicePlan document:

```
{
    "_id": "62c9d3f6053cf23ca515fad1",
    "startDate": "2022-07-01T08:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2023-01-01T08:00:00.000Z",
    "client": "6205a8313fe12d6b4ec354c4",
    "goals": [
        {
            "title": "Clean",
            "dataCollection": "prog note",
            "staffRole": "instruction",
            "frequency": 4,
            "location": "a place",
            "projectedHours": 4,
            "materials": "stuff",
            "currentStatus": "This box needs to be bigger on the form.",
            "quote": "a quote",
            "measurement": "so and so will do such and such by when and then",
            "plan": "This needs formatting",
            "_id": "62cb25494d9ca383237c9f7c",
            "createdAt": "2022-07-10T19:15:21.693Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-12T00:15:22.945Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "Budget",
            "dataCollection": "prog ntoes",
            "staffRole": "Instruct",
            "frequency": 4,
            "location": "Home",
            "projectedHours": 4,
            "materials": "stuff",
            "currentStatus": "blah blah stuff stuff",
            "quote": "words",
            "measurement": "measure this by that",
            "plan": "steps ",
            "_id": "62ccbb36fbc246eff7c457d6",
            "createdAt": "2022-07-12T00:07:18.408Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-12T00:07:18.408Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "Cook",
            "dataCollection": "prog ntoe",
            "staffRole": "demonstrate",
            "frequency": 4,
            "location": "home",
            "projectedHours": 8,
            "materials": "cook supplise",
            "currentStatus": "blah blah cook stuff",
            "quote": "more words",
            "measurement": "measurement",
            "plan": "plans",
            "_id": "62ccbd40bf77e35122c03831",
            "createdAt": "2022-07-12T00:16:00.286Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-12T00:16:00.286Z"
        }
    ],
    "notes": [
        {
            "title": "Payee",
            "note": "So and so is their payee",
            "_id": "62cc9f3fdd4e1f85993d5c19",
            "createdAt": "2022-07-11T22:07:59.159Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-11T22:07:59.159Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "Family Input",
            "note": "None at this time.",
            "_id": "62cdb06fbf77e35122c0384c",
            "createdAt": "2022-07-12T17:33:35.364Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-12T17:33:35.364Z"
        }
    ],
    "submittedBy": [],
    "approvedBy": [],
    "sentBy": [],
    "createdAt": "2022-07-09T19:16:06.948Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-07-12T17:33:35.364Z",
    "__v": 11,
    "type": "Annual",
    "reportDate": "2022-07-01T23:40:54.898Z"
}
```

I've checked the models, routes, and controllers, nothing is set up any different (other than the particular names/endpoints) from the other working calls I have elsewhere in the app. Whats really confusing is even with the .select() it is still returning the full doc. I'm assuming it is something super simple, but I can't figure it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
So now I'm really lost. It certainly is not query, since I replaced it with just random string so it should break. But instead I still get the full parent doc.

```
//heres the index line-
app.use("/planapi/goals", goalRoutes)

//route-
router.route("/:planId").get(getClientReportGoals)

//controller
exports.getClientReportGoals = async (req, res) => {

    jsdfjlnljn
    
 }
```

And when I put in the call to postman:
http://localhost:5000/planapi/goals/62c9d3f6053cf23ca515fad1/

I'm still getting the full parent doc as shown above... Anyone have any idea how thats happening? It should just crash.

Comment: Try this: `const servicePlan = await ServicePlan.findOne( { _id: req.params.planId }, { goals: 1 });`. Enclose this in a try-catch block and see how it works.

Comment: I've gone through that, for some reason I still get the whole parent doc. I doubt that it is this since I've checked the routes/index/models, but is there somewhere in mongoose that would always return the parent doc? I know with the find method alone it will, but with select, or the other ways to select specific fields, it shouldn't return the full doc

Comment: I even went so far as to set it with { goals: 1, *all other fields*: 0} and it still returns the full doc

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had 3 routes files coming off a single starting point on the index file. Each had a separate url structure from there, however, one of them had a dynamic field as its starting point, and because of that, the subdoc routes were all running through that routes file. Simple mistake, and just another reason to be more explicit in writing the code out.